# Prevent re-render of Await in React Suspense

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-suspense

I am using `Suspense` from React, and `Await` from React-Router-DOM to wait for a promise and return JSX on resolve, but in most cases I want to call some functions like `navigate` or something else, then the functions are called twice. I want to prevent that.

Loader

```js
export const Loader = async ({ params }) => {
  CheckAuth();
  let fetch_data = fetchApi('auth/activate-account', 'POST', { verify_token: params.verify_token });
  return defer({ loaderPromise: fetch_data });
}
// this loader is called in the Route loader prop
```

```
const VerifyToken = () => {            
  const loaderData = useLoaderData();
            
  const navigate = useNavigate();
            
  const { showAlert } = useGeneral();
            
  return (
    <React.Suspense fallback={<PreLoader />}>
      <Await resolve={loaderData.loaderPromise}>
        {(resolvedData) => {
          if (resolvedData.type === "warning") {
            showAlert(resolvedData.type, resolvedData.msg);
            navigate('/Auth/Login', { replace: true });
            return null;
          }
          return (
            { JSX }
          );
        }}
      </Await>
    </React.Suspense>
  );
};
```

This causes calling the `navigate` and `showAlert` functions twice. I want to prevent that or use another approach or other methods.

I tried this:

```
let loaderRef = React.useRef(false);
    
<React.Suspense fallback={<PreLoader />}>
  <Await resolve={loaderData.loaderPromise}>
    {(resolvedData) => {
      if (!loaderRef.current) {
        showAlert(resolvedData.type, resolvedData.msg);
        loaderRef.current = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
          navigate('/Auth/Login', { replace: true });
        }, 0);
        return null;
      }
    }}
  </Await>
</React.Suspense>
```

This works but not efficient in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there is some rendering issue being exposed by a `React.StrictMode` component higher up the ReactTree, specific lifecycle functions are double-invoked in non-production builds to expose logical issues in your code like unintentional side-effects.

Abstract the unintentional side-effect of showing the alert and navigating into a React component that can use the `useEffect` hook to correctly issue an intentional side-effect to show the alert and conditionally redirect or render the specified JSX content.

Example:

```
const DataHandler = ({ children, resolvedData }) => {
  const { showAlert } = useGeneral();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (resolvedData.type === "warning") {
      showAlert(resolvedData.type, resolvedData.msg);
    }
  }, [resolvedData]);

  if (resolvedData.type === "warning") {
    return <Navigate to='/Auth/Login' replace />;
  }

  return children;
};
```

```
const VerifyToken = () => {        
  const loaderData = useLoaderData();
  
  return (
    <React.Suspense fallback={<PreLoader />}>
      <Await resolve={loaderData.loaderPromise}>
        {(resolvedData) => {
          return (
            <DataHandler resolvedData={resolvedData}>
              { JSX }
            </DataHandler>
          );
        }}
      </Await>
    </React.Suspense>
  );
};
```

Comment: I have tried this way earlier,but this still causes re-renders,the re-renders are being caused by Await component ,i am not stick to this React.Suspense and Await method i just need a better solution to optimise my app,to load data faster,manage errors and use parallel loaders,if there is any other approach or package i would be glad to here from you.Thank you

Comment: @FarazRabbani How exactly are you verifying component "rerenders"? Think you could create a simple [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue you describe that we could inspect live?

Comment: sorry for delay here is the codesandbox link https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-await-and-suspense-k5rmgs

Comment: @FarazRabbani No worries. I don't see extra "rerenders" happening in the code in your sandbox beyond the expected renders. What I see is the `React.StrictMode` doing its job, e.g. it double-invokes *some* lifecycle methods/functions and double-mounts components as a way to help you find potential issues/side-effects in your logic. What I see in your sandbox is completely expected and normal behavior. If you comment out the `StrictMode` component in `index.js` you'll see the "normal" production behavior.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a full picture to help you, but I'll try to guest
Are you using react in StrictMode in development?
It will make React rerender twice every component trying to avoid errors

If is not the case, please provide a way to test the application

https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#strictmode

> **Strict Mode enables the following development-only behaviors:**
>
> Your components will re-render an extra time to find bugs caused by impure rendering.
> Your components will re-run Effects an extra time to find bugs caused by missing Effect cleanup.
> Your components will be checked for usage of deprecated APIs.

Comment: React.StrictMode is on for my app and i heard this is very crucial for production as well,so i have no plans of removing it,i would be glad to hear a better solution from you.Thank you

Comment: Yes, you're right, it is not good to remove react strict mode, but understand that it will make the app rerender in development env. Have you check it in a production env? The rerender continues?

Comment: yes i have checked in production too,the re-renders are there shortly i will provide a sandbox link